# Can I download Minecraft for PC on my Android device, then later install it on my PC?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I would like to install the full version of Minecraft for PC. If I download it on Android, Can I later transfer the `.exe` file over to PC?

Will this install the full version of Minecraft?

[image: Minecraft Homepage on Android]

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference between downloading it on Android and then transferring it to PC, and just downloading it on PC.

If you would have the full version when you download it on PC, it'll be the same thing if you download it on Android.

Comment: It might make a difference if you browse the Minecraft page from a mobile device. A lot of sites will detect your device and 'default' you to downloading the version for that device. It should still be possible to find the PC version somewhere, but it might be somewhat hidden away.

Comment: Additionally, you'll download the installer which installs the launcher, which only then downloads the actual game from the net. Your PC needs at least temporary network connectivity to verify your account, and download the latest update.